# Strange Camel behaviour on apache karaf

Tags: spring, apache-camel, apache-karaf, spring-dsl

So I have some routes on camel spring dsl which behaves and work just as expected. However when I deploy these routes on karaf they behave different, for example
1) I have this condition `<when><simple>${body} == null</simple></when>` it evaluates to true even if body is empty on in karaf

2) I have one processor where I check if condition if(body != null), it is evaluating to true even though body is not null.

Is there any specific reason that it works just fine in every other environment but fails in karaf.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is

```
<when><simple>${body} == null</simple></when>
```

Notice you are missing a `$`

Comment: Could be streaming see this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html